# Subclassed Binding works at runtime, but not in designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, windows-phone-8

In order to save typing and make code more readable, I subclassed the Binding class to make it use a specific source:

```
public class MyBinding : Binding
{
    private void SetSource()
    {
        Source = Application.Current.Resources["Translator"];
    }

    public TBinding()
    {
        SetSource();
    }

    public TBinding(string path) : base(path)
    {
        SetSource();
    }
}
```

So instead of writing this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path='hello', Source={StaticResource Translator}}"/>
```

I can write this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{local:MyBinding Path='hello'}"/>
```

That works perfectly at runtime, but the designer doesn't show the correct text. Instead it shows the type of the MyBinding class.

**Is there any way to make this work in the Visual Studio designer?**

Comment: Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use d:DataContext or d:DesignData in your XAML to pull in sample data.  There is an article describing this [here](http://markmacumber.net/2012/08/design-time-support-in-windows-8-c-xaml.html).